# Step-By-Step Content Type in d7?

Tags: views, nodes

I want to create a tutorial content type, something where people can upload images, title, body, etc into 'steps'; each step would then be linked together.
The users can upload an unlimited number of steps for the entire node. It is very similar to the instructables.com site. How could I achieve that?

By the way, someone did ask a similar question about this using Drupal 6. The suggestions were to use a story book content type, or to use CCK field grouping. I don't understand how to do those things in d7.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of using the book structure or field groups would be exactly the same in D7 as it would have been in D6. However, the CCK multigroup module would be a much better fit and would check on it's D7 status (I tried, but it's spread over several issues in the queue)

Comment: I'm confused. The Field group module says it does not support multigroup like it did in d6. Multigroup doesn't have support for d7. Does this mean this functionality is not available in d7?  What are my options here?

Comment: Not sure. You will have to do some research and check out the queues.